# npm build failing due to rescript cannot handle multiple files error

Tags: npm-start, rescript

Error:

```
rescript: [32/234] src/C...ts/Common/Transition.cmj
FAILED: src/Components/Common/Transition.cmj
can not handle multiple files
```

Caused when I ran:

```
npm start
```

or

```
yarn start
```

**bsconfig.json** contents [name doesn't have any spaces]

```
{
    "name": "care_fe",
    "reason": {
        "react-jsx": 3
    },
    "bsc-flags": ["-bs-super-errors"],
    "sources": [{
        "dir": "src",
        "subdirs": true
    }],
....
...so on
```

**package.json** contents

dependencies:
"@rescript/react": "^0.10.3",
"rescript-material-ui": "^2.1.2"

devDependencies:
"rescript": "^9.1.4"

**Transition.res** contents

```
type reactClass
module Transition = {
  @module("./Transition.tsx") @react.component
  external make: (
    ~show: option<bool>,
    ~enter: string,
    ~enterFrom: string,
    ~enterTo: string,
    ~leave: string,
    ~leaveFrom: string,
    ~leaveTo: string,
    ~children: 'a,
  ) => React.element = "default"
}

@react.component
let make = (
  ~show=None,
  ~enter="",
  ~enterFrom="",
  ~enterTo="",
  ~leave="",
  ~leaveFrom="",
  ~leaveTo="",
  ~children,
) => <Transition show enter enterFrom enterTo leave leaveFrom leaveTo> children </Transition>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple modules named `Transition`?

Comment: there is Transition.tsx and Transition.res. The module file is just Transition.res So no multiple modules

Comment: Can you publish the contents of `lib/bs/build.ninja` in a gist or something?

Comment: Related: https://forum.rescript-lang.org/t/error-can-not-handle-multiple-files/1368/7 and https://github.com/rescript-lang/rescript-compiler/issues/5087

Comment: contents of lib/bs/build.ninja : https://gist.github.com/Pragati1610/5c3da29d375bc6d56f86e06c28423f3a

Comment: Regarding the related issues: in the question I posted I added bsconfig.json contents  and that the name doesn't have any spaces, so the issue seems something else

Comment: Yep, but it does suggest that spaces elsewhere might cause problems if ii goes through to the build commands unescaped. Such as having `GDC Care` in the path. Does it work if you move it to a path that does not contain spaces?

Comment: No worries. You should report this as a bug though. From the `.ninja` file, and assuming that ninja will properly escape the `$g_finger` variable where used, it looks like the `-bs-gentype` path specifically is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it seems the rescript build system has a bug where the current working directory is passed to a build command unescaped, and so a project residing in a path that contains spaces will be interpreted as multiple paths, hence the "multiple files" error.

The workaround is to move the project to a path that does not contain spaces, until the bug is hopefully (soon) fixed.